# Как найти разницу значений в двух двумерных массивах?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, матрицы

Как найти разницу значений в двух двумерных массивах?

```
arr1 = [[35,70],[433,70],[35,73],[433,73],[35,154],[433,154]] 
arr2 = [[433,70],[433,154],[433,73],[35,154],[1,2,3]]
```

В результате должно быть:

```
res = [[35,70],[35,73]]
```

Мой код:

```js
var arr1 = [[35,70],[433,70],[35,73],[433,73],[35,154],[433,154]];
var arr2 = [[433,70],[433,154],[433,73],[35,154],[1,2,3]];
var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) 
{ 
  res.push(arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1)); 
}
console.log(res);//нужно [[35,70],[35,73]]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: как Вы думаете, что возвращает `Array.indexOf`?

Comment: @Igor Позицию значения в массиве

Comment: хорошо, но все элемeнты в Ваших массивах - разные объекты

Comment: то есть все Ваши вызовы `indexOf` возвращают `-1`

Comment: @Igor Как тогда поступить? Пробовал перевести в строку JSON.stringify, но не получилось все равно найти нужные элементы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, что у вас не получилось с JSON.stringify

```
arr1 = [[35,70],[433,70],[35,73],[433,73],[35,154],[433,154]] 
arr2 = [[433,70],[433,154],[433,73],[35,154],[1,2,3]]

arr1 = arr1.map(function(x) { return JSON.stringify(x) })
arr2 = arr2.map(function(x) { return JSON.stringify(x) })

function diffTest(x) {
   for(var i=0; i < arr2.length; i++)  {
      if (arr2[i] === x) return false;
      }
   return true;   
}
diff = arr1.filter(diffTest).map(function(x) { return JSON.parse(x) }) // [ [ 35, 70 ], [ 35, 73 ] ]
```

Можно и массивы сравнивать в цикле, без json

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr1 = [[35, 70], [433, 70], [35, 73], [433, 73], [35, 154], [433, 154]];
var arr2 = [[433, 70], [433, 154], [433, 73], [35, 154], [1, 2, 3]];

function AnotB(a, b)
{
    var diff = [], elA, elB, i, j, found;

    loopA: for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        elA = a[i];
        found = false;

        loopB: for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            elB = b[j];

            if (elA.length !== elB.length) continue loopB;

            for (k = 0; k < elA.length; k++) {
                if (elA[k] !== elB[k]) continue loopB;
            }

            found = true;
            break loopB;
        }

        if (!found) diff.push(elA);
    }

    return diff;
}

console.log(AnotB(arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за ответы я так же сделал свой вариант:

```js
var arr1 = [[35,70],[433,70],[35,73],[433,73],[35,154],[433,154]] 
var arr2 = [[433,70],[433,154],[433,73],[35,154]]

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) 
{ 
 if(!isItemInArray(arr2,arr1[i])==true){
    console.log(arr1[i]);
 }
  
   
}


function isItemInArray(array, item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][0] == item[0] && array[i][1] == item[1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```